# Intro to C: Addition and Printing

Tags: c, printf, calculator, addition

I'm trying to making a rudimentary calculator that can perform a variety of arithmetic functions, starting with addition! Right now I've got the basic logic of it worked out, but I'm not sure exactly how to take two inputs and print it out!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char mychar;
    int a;
    int op1;
    int op2;

    printf("Welcome to Andrew Hu's calculator program!\n"); //Greeting

    while(1)
    {    printf("Enter a mathematical operation to perform:\n");
        scanf("%c", &mychar);

    if(mychar == '+') //Valid Operators
        a = 1;
    else
        a = 0;


    if(a == 0) //Operator Checker, error if invalid
        printf("\nError, not a valid operator\n");
    else if(a == 1){
        printf("%c\n", &mychar),
        printf("Enter OP1:\n"),

       /* not sure what to put here to echo the character as a decimal*/

        printf("Enter OP2:\n"),

         /* not sure what to put here to echo the character as a decimal either*/

        printf("Result of %d %c %d = %d\n", op1, mychar, op2, (op1 + op2) )
        /* this last line I'm not too sure of. I'm trying to print out the expression
           which is op1 + op2 = the sum of both. */
              ;
    }
    }
```

Comment: What you must first do, is find out different methods of input. The most commonly used one (for a beginner), is `scanf`. Then, you must read [`scanf`'s manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html). Start coding _only_ when you understand how to use `scanf`.

Comment: @Andrew Hu - do not forget to accept the answers, that have solved your problem / question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use scanf statement to take the inputs,just the same way you have taken mathematical    operators.A switch case statement would be good to implement the calculator.

```
scanf(" %d",&op1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `scanf` function to read in a floating-point value like

```
double op1 = 0.0;
scanf("%lf", &op1);
```

The `%lf` denotes to read the entered value as a `float`-value.

As you enter the values on the command-line they will be displayed.

```
else if(a == 1){
    printf("%c\n", mychar), // don't use & with printf as it will print the address of mychar
    printf("Enter OP1:\n"),

   double op1 = 0.0;
   scanf("%lf", &op1);

    printf("Enter OP2:\n"),

    double op2 = 0.0;
    scanf("%lf", &op2);

    if(a == 1)
        printf("Result of %lf + %lf = %lf\n", op1, op2, (op1 + op2) );
        }
```

Comment: I'd remove the comments to make the answer a bit shorter. But +1.

Comment: Is there an advantage using lf over f? lf is 64 and f is 32 so just more precision?

Comment: `%lf` is capable of reading `double`-values, while `%f` reads "ordinary" `float`-values. So depending on your desire, you can interchange them.